# How to remove nothing from a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

From a matrix `M`,

```
> (M <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I want to remove/keep columns by condition and put the result into a list. There's no problem as long as the condition consists of integers without `c(NA, 0)`, e.g.

```
cv1 <- 1:3
lapply(cv1, function(x) M[, -x])
```

For the case there's no column to remove I tried to add `NA` or `0` to the condition vector, but it won't work.

```
cv2 <- c(NA, 1:3)
cv3 <- 0:3

> lapply(cv2, function(x) M[, -x])[[1]]
[1] NA NA NA

> lapply(cv3, function(x) M[, -x])[[1]]

[1,]
[2,]
[3,]
```

I know I can do

```
lapply(cv2, function(x) {
  if (is.na(x))
    M
  else
    M[, -x]
})
```

but I wonder if there's a simpler way.

***Actually question:***

What strikes me in the first place is that the matrix disappears instead of remaining complete in following cases, although I'm actually trying to remove nothing:

```
M[, -(na.omit(NA))]
M[, na.omit(-(NA))]
M[, -0]
M[, -logical(0)]

# [1,]
# [2,]
# [3,]
```

or

```
> M[, -NULL]
Error in -NULL : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Can somebody explain the reason and the advantage of this behavior, and/or how to say it right?

Comment: Maybe you can use setdiff(1:3, x)

Comment: You could remove those empty values before passing them into `lapply` itself.

Comment: @Cettt Nice approach, works fine, thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah The point is the attempt to remove an empty set, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple:  the minus sign in `-x` isn't treated as something special, it's just a regular mathematical operation.  So `-0` is the same as `0`, and `-NA` is the same as `NA`.

@Cettt gave one answer:  `setdiff(seq_len(ncol(M)), x)` will give the column numbers other than `x`.  You can do the same sort of thing using logical indexing as `seq_len(ncol(M)) != x` will work if `x` is a number, but not if `x` is `NA`.  If you really need to handle that case too, you could use `is.na(x) | seq_len(ncol(M)) != x`, but @Cettt's solution looks simpler.